# Envio de mails Gmail - Heroku

Tags: php, laravel, heroku

> Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at 530 5.5.1

Tengo problemas con envio de mail desde el servidor Heroku.
desde *localhost*, los envia perfectamente.
Aqui esta mi  .ENV :

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp  
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com  
MAIL_PORT=587  
MAIL_USERNAME=mi@mail.com  
MAIL_PASSWORD="xxxxxxxx"  
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

ya intente con 
`MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail` en `MAIL_PORT=` y no funcionó.

¿Puede que tenga algo pendiente de  configurar en  HEROKU?

Comment: activaste el uso de aplicaciones menos seguras desde gmail?

Comment: Si,  y tambien probé con la autenticacion en dos pasos , generando el  APP PASSWORD.  
 pero en ninguno de los casos funciona